# Change default image repository in Openshift 4.7

Tags: docker, kubernetes, repository, openshift, redhat

How can I change default docker image registry in Openshift ?
I already modified `/etc/containers/registries.conf` in workers and master nodes and put something like this but it didn't work.

```
[[registry]]
prefix = "my_private_registry.com"
location = "my_private_registry.com"
insecure = false
```

How can I change the default repo?
Thank you

Comment: This question might be better suited for [sf].

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in [OpenShift documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/openshift_images/image-configuration.html):

> containerRuntimeSearchRegistries: Registries for which image pull and
> push actions are allowed using image short names. All other registries
> are blocked.

So you can configure something like:

```
apiVersion: config.openshift.io/v1
kind: Image
metadata:
  annotations:
    release.openshift.io/create-only: "true"
  name: cluster
spec:
  registrySources:
    containerRuntimeSearchRegistries: 
    - my_private_registry.com
    - quay.io
    - registry.redhat.io
```